# Element not interactable Selenium no other unique id to radio button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

When I inspect the code of the button it brings me to this section:

```
<input type="radio" name="chosen" value="UniqueNameExample">
```

Trying to find element within this that I am able to click(). Using the value results in element not interactable. both the type and name repeat throughout page. Button is loaded and clickable by cursor by time code is ran.

Code I am currently trying:

```
  time.sleep(3)
   action19 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='UniqueNameExample']")
    action19.click()
```

Also tried:

```
action19 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='radio'][@name='chosen'][@value='UnquieNameExample']")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes elements on a website just aren't interactable to selenium. There's a reason why, I just don't know what it is in this specific scenario. However, when an element is being particularly stubborn, I copy it's js path, and run an execute script that uses javascript to click the element instead.

`((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('jsPath').click();");`

Comment: Oh interesting I will give that a try! How do I find the jsPath?

Comment: If you right click on the element in dev tools, hover over copy, and click copy jspath

Comment: I will say, my answer won't work directly as written. I grabbed that from c#. The script itself will work, but I know python will be something more like `driver.execute_script` than `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript`

Comment: Got it to work with `time.sleep(5)
js = "document.querySelector('#bxlist > li:nth-child(5) > div > input[type=radio]').click();"
driver.execute_script(js)
time.sleep(3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with CSS selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='UniqueNameExample']").click()
```

Also, make sure the element is interactable at the moment you are trying to click on it. Use some waiting strategy to achieve this, for example you can utilize WebDriverWait with ExpectedCondition. You can find more info [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#).

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. The value of the *`value`* attribute sould have been *`UniqueNameExample`* instead of `UniqueNameExample`. Your effective line of code would be:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='radio'][@name='chosen'][@value='UniqueNameExample']").click()
```

Ideally to interact with `<input>` elements you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='radio'][name='chosen'][value='UniqueNameExample']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='radio'][@name='chosen' and @value='UniqueNameExample']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Updated code the @was in original code. All the code I tried that you recommended still gives me "element not interactable".

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for the element to be clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

EW = 20  # EW stands for explicit_wait
WebDriverWait(driver, EW).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH,
         "//input[@value='UniqueNameExample']")
    )).click()
```